# longer than it is wide

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Are the folowing sentences all natural? If so, what's the difference?

> a. The shape is longer than it is wide.

> b. The shape is longer than wide.

> c. The shape is more long than wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is the most correct and technical.

B is incorrect.

C is correct, but also has the feel of discussion how to describe it more generally, e.g., “Would you say it was more long or wide? Or maybe it’s sort of round? Or maybe more like an oblong kind of shape?”

Comment: Thank you. How does A differ from C?

Comment: A sounds more technical, because it’s an explicit comparison of dimensions (width versus length). With A, you know precisely what the person is talking about. It’s also just a very idiomatic way of saying it.

Comment: @ChrisMack `it is` or `its` which is correct in A? I thought it should be `its`

Comment: @doğukan It would be "it is" - I guess you could say "longer than its width", but this isn't idiomatic, and kind of sounds a bit funny.

Comment: @ChrisMack thanks for explanation. it had confused me.